# Notation for Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

So I have seen a few different ways to denote Expectation (expected value). I want to make sure this is just the case of different people using different symbols/letters and not altogether different formulas.

First notation
[image]

Second notation
[image: second]

Third one

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your pictures for 2 and 3 failed to load

Comment: Should be working now?

Comment: They all are the same, $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is the expectation of $X$, what bothers you here ? (I assume that in the third image, $Y=g(X)$ so that indeed $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\sum_{x}g(x)p_X(x)$)

Comment: @Tuvasbien The main thing that bothers me is I'm not sure what the purpose of Y =g(X) is?

Comment: The definition of the expectancy is $\mathbb{E}[X]:=\sum_x xp_X(x)$, there is a theorem that states that for all function $f$, $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\sum_x f(x)p_X(x)$ under some assumptions. The third equality is simply the application of this formula, if you have a random variable defined by $Y:=g(X)$ ($Y=X^2-4$ for instance), then $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_x g(x)p_X(x)$. It is widely use to lighten the calculus.

Comment: I would say this notation is all equally bad.  It seems to assume $X$ is discrete, it leaves some notation unspecified (what is the relation between $Y$ and $g(x)$, for example, and what is $f(x)$, and what is $S$?), and does not precisely specify what sets or limits we are summing over. Arguably, these "definitions" assume you already know the definition.

Comment: @Michael So how should it look?

Comment: If $X$ is a discrete random variable that takes values a finite or countably infinite set $S_X$ then $$E[X] = \sum_{x \in S_X}x P[X=x]$$ assuming the summation is well defined (which holds, for example, whenever $\sum_{x \in S_X} |x| P[X=x] <\infty$). If you want to use $p_X(x)=P[X=x]$ you can substitute that.

Comment: @Tuvasbien or Michael In the first notation, the x in the (x) is the probability? and the x right after the sigma symbol is the numerical value?